# MySQL bin log missing data?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqlbinlog

I'm trying to make heads and tails of my binary logs and am coming up short. I have many entries similar to the following from mysqlbinlog but I'm missing log data that I know should be there.

```
# at 1050548
#130617 18:40:03 server id 1  end_log_pos 1050619   Query   thread_id=844988    exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1371519603/*!*/;
BEGIN
/*!*/;
# at 1050619
# at 1050782
#130617 18:40:03 server id 1  end_log_pos 1050809   Xid = 33121028
COMMIT/*!*/;
```

It's puzzling because I get expected SQL in the mysqlbinlog output for statements executed in phpmyadmin but those coming from other PHP-based remote web servers appear to not be recorded.

My settings bin logging are:

```
bin_log = /path_to_sql_incrementals
binlog_ignore_db = mysql
```

Am I missing a logging option?

Mysql 5.0.95 / CentOS 5.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't log to the binary log file when you use direct database.table syntax in your update queries (eg. UPDATE Foo.Bar SET ...). My web application never specifies a default database so the data is never logged.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-rules-db-options.html

I solved the problem my calling mysql_select_db before my INSERT and UPDATE queries.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `--base64-output=decode-rows` and `--verbose` options with `mysqlbinlog` or you will not always see everything that's in the log.

You should also consider removing `binlog_ignore_db` from your configuration, because this not only prevents logging changes to the `mysql` schema, it also stops logging of events from your session that reference other schemas any time you `USE mysql` until you `USE` another database because of the way [replication rules are interpreted](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-rules.html).

Comment: I've tried with both --verbose and --base64-ouput – neither of which had any affect.

Comment: Also, you've tried them together, right?  Because they do need to be used together.  If that's not it, then it's very likely that either your `binlog_ignore_db` is preventing things from being logged *or* ... uh ... you're not expecting `SELECT` queries to be logged -- right?  The binlog only captures `DDL` and `DML`, not `SELECT`.

Comment: Tried them together - check.  Not expecting SELECTS.  Looking for INSERT and UPDATE specifically.  I've dug into numerous examples of mysqlbinlog and it just seems like the data isn't there...

Comment: Have you removed the `binlog_ignore_db` and restarted the server?  Also, what are your `binlog_format` and `tx_isolation` set to?

Comment: Ah... so, I've tried to duplicate what you are seeing... are you using *any* other arguments, such as `--database`? ... you shouldn't be ... *just* use `mysqlbinlog --verbose --base64-output=decode-rows *filename*` ...

Comment: I have no settings for binlog_format or tx_isolation – so whatever is the default.  I have tried with and without the --database switch.  Does using it prevent --verbose and --base64-output from working as expected?

Comment: It definitely can.  `--database` changes mysqlbinlog behavior and `binlog_ignore_db` changes what's actually logged in ways that are *very* counter-intuitive without an understanding of the intricacies of replication and in both cases they make statements invisible (from output) or missing (from binlogs) because MySQL has a concept of the "current" database at any given moment for any given session that isn't always the same as what your query references.  This is *especially* true if the queries in question use qualified table names, e.g. "UPDATE my_db.table1..." vs. "UPDATE table1..."

Comment: Nope, no dice without the --database option either.  I've had to move the bin log file to another machine because MySQL 5.0.95 didn't have support for verbose in mysqlbinlog.  Could this be an issue with MySQL being dated?